# How to properly call and use variables in jinja2 template with embedded Python code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have this two classes:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    person_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    #gender = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    nacionality = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    marital_status = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    profession = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    SSN = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    driver_license = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    address = db.PostalAddressProperty(required = True)

class ContractingParty(db.Model):
    person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person, required=True, collection_name="party_to_contracts")
    contract = db.ReferenceProperty(Contract, required=True)
    condition = db.StringProperty()
```

I want to pass a query of ContractingParty entities to my jinja2 template. Then with a `for loop`, I want to acess the data I really want, from Person entities. The Contracting Party query is being passed to jinja2 (if I test it, I can see something like this: `[<main.ContractingParty object at 0x0492D770>]`). But the `for loop` bellow doesn't working, no information of the `for loop` is being shown in my brownser. How could I fix it?

```
{% for party in parties %}
     <li> {{party.person.person_name}} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you render the template.  If Rostyslav's answer isn't helping, it's probably a problem with the template context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you've made a mistake in your for loop construct, colon character must be omitted:

```
{% for party in parties %}
```

The whole code must be changed to actually render objects passed to templates. You can't execute Python code here, you must obey Jinja2 syntax:

```
{% for party in parties %}
    <li>{{ party.person.profession}}</li>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to make some assignment use **set** Jinja's tag:

```
{% set person = party.person %}
```

I hope you've got the idea, here is a [link](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) with much more clarification

Comment: Thanks, Rostyslav Dzinko. I corrected that, but the error persistis. Nothing (in the for loop) is shown. Other template parts are ok.

Comment: Let's advance. Jinja2 is a template engine and those template is *not a python code*, so you must obey its rules. *profession = person.profession* won't be processed like python code (assignment), but jinja2 syntax allows you to access object attributes, so you can render attributes like {{ party.nacionality }}.